# Hibernate good practice, lazy/eager loading and saving/deleting children (help me Hibernate sensei)

Tags: java, hibernate

So, I have found myself in quite a pickle regarding Hibernate. When I started developing my web application, I used "eager" loading everywhere so I could easily access children, parents etc.

After a while, I ran into my first problem - re-saving of deleted objects. Multiple stackoverflow threads suggested that I should remove the object from all the collections that it's in. Reading those suggestions made my "spidey sense" tickle as my relations weren't really simple and I had to iterate multiple objects which made my code look kind of ugly and made me wonder if this was the best approach.

For example, when deleting Employee (that belongs to User in a sense that User can act as multiple different Employees). Let's say Employee can leave Feedback to Party, so Employee can have multiple Feedback and Party can have multiple Feedback. Additionally, both Employee and Party belong to some kind of a parent object, let's say an Organization. Basically, we have:

```
class User {
  // Has many
  Set<Employee> employees;
  // Has many
  Set<Organization> organizations;
  // Has many through employees
  Set<Organization> associatedOrganizations;
}

class Employee {
  // Belongs to
  User user;
  // Belongs to
  Organization organization;
  // Has many
  Set<Feedback> feedbacks;
}

class Organization {
  // Belongs to
  User user;
  // Has many
  Set<Employee> employees;
  // Has many
  Set<Party> parties;
}

class Party {
  // Belongs to
  Organization organization;
  // Has many
  Set<Feedback> feedbacks;
}

class Feedback {
  // Belongs to
  Party party;
  // Belongs to
  Employee employee;
}
```

Here's what I ended up with when deleting an employee:

```
// First remove feedbacks related to employee
Iterator<Feedback> iter = employee.getFeedbacks().iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
  Feedback feedback = iter.next();
  iter.remove();
  feedback.getParty().getFeedbacks().remove(feedback);
  session.delete(feedback);
}
session.update(employee);

// Now remove employee from organization
Organization organization = employee.getOrganization();
organization.getEmployees().remove(employee);
session.update(organization);
```

This is, by my definition, ugly. I would've assumed that by using

```
@Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
```

then Hibernate would magically remove Employee from all associations by simply doing:

```
session.delete(employee);
```

instead I get:

```
Error during managed flush [deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations)
```

So, in order to try to get my code a bit cleaner and maybe even optimized (sometimes lazy fetch is enough, sometimes I need eager), I tried lazy fetching almost everything and hoping that if I do, for example:

```
employee.getFeedbacks()
```

then the feedbacks are nicely fetched without any problem but nope, everything breaks:

```
failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: ..., could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

The next thing I thought about was removing the possibility for objects to insert/delete their related children objects but that would probably be a bad idea performance-wise - inserting every object separately with

`child.parent=parent`

instead of in a bulk with

`parent.children().add(children)`.

Finally, I saw that multiple people recommended creating my own custom queries and stuff but at that point, why should I even bother with Hibernate? Is there really no good way to handle my problem relatively clean or am I missing something or am I an idiot?

Comment: Generally speaking it's preferrable to use lazy loading because you can always switch to eager with `FETCH JOIN`, but you can't turn an eager load into a lazy one. Hibernate is a lot trickier than it looks, which comes often as a surprise to less experienced programmers who get the sense that "I don't have to understand databases, because everything is saved by magic". Unfortunately that extends only to very simple usage.

Comment: But what should I do about the fetch join if I don't have any specific queries, just annotations?

Comment: That's the "very simple usage" I was referring to. You can't expect to build complex functionality that doesn't have specialized queries. Even if it managed to work, it would absolutely destroy the performance.

Comment: How are those relations mapped by annotations? Shouldn't it be like @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)?

Comment: I didn't include the annotations. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly it's all about cascading through simple `1:N` relations. In that case Hibernate can do the job rather well:

```
@Entity
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
        mappedBy = "post", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
public class Comment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Post post;
}
```

Code:

```
Post post = newPost();
doInTransaction(session -> {
    session.delete(post);
});
```

Generates:

```
delete from Comment where id = 1
delete from Comment where id = 2
delete from Post where id = 1
```

But if you have some other (synthetic) collections, Hibernate has no chance to know which ones, so you have to handle them yourself.

As for Hibernate and custom queries, Hibernate provides HQL which is more compact then traditional SQL, but still is less transparent then annotations.